# System.Text.Json JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(...) cannot deserialize object[] type

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json, .net-5

I want to parse my `JSON` string value as an `object[]` type, but it always return `System.Text.Json.JsonElement[]` type.

```
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[]>("[\"abcd\",\"efgh\",\"ijkl\",\"mnop\"]", null);
foreach (var _ in data) Console.WriteLine(_.GetType().FullName);
```

Expected Output:

```
System.Object
System.Object
System.Object
System.Object
```

Actual Output:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonElement
System.Text.Json.JsonElement
System.Text.Json.JsonElement
System.Text.Json.JsonElement
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

You are getting the array of `Object` elements, but actual elements are of type `JsonElement`. It is inherited from `Object`.

Moreover, you can not store `\"abcd\"` string in an `Object` typed area of memory. It will be `string` or `JsonElement` or something else. But you can keep the reference to it in the `Object` type variable.
e.g.
`foreach (Object _ in data) Console.WriteLine(_.GetType().FullName);`
will also work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried `foreach (Object _ in data) Console.WriteLine(_.GetType().FullName);` but it still returns `JsonElement` not `Object`. I need to store them as `object[]` because I need to type cast them into another primitive types like `string`, `float`, `int`, etc. If I store them as `JsonElement`, it cannot not be casted as `string` and the others.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not feasible.
The json deserializer is not so smart. It does not know the exact type of these values and can not distinguish if it's a string or int, or float. You'll have to do it manually in your case.
JsonElement has Get... and TryGet...methods for that.
Here is the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-5.0

Comment: Oh I see, okay I think I'll do that conversion manually then. Thank you for the explanation.